# Returning values with &&

Tags: javascript, operators, return

What does it mean to return a value with &&?

```
else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {

    // It uses the traditional ' text-align' style of rule writing, 
    // instead of textAlign
    name = name.replace(/([A-Z]) /g, " -$1" );
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    // Get the style object and get the value of the property (if it exists)
    var s = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, " ") ;
    return s && s.getPropertyValue(name) ;
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you don't return a value with `&&`, you rather return a value based on other values. :)

Answer (score 69):

`return a && b` means "return a if a is falsy, return b if a is truthy".

It is equivalent to

```
if (a) return b;
else return a;
```

Comment: Isn't easier to use `(a) ? true : false` while using return?

Comment: @AlexanderKim `a ? true : false` is just `!!a` as in `if (a) { ... }`.

`return a || b` is if a return a else return b and this is just the opposite.

Answer (score 16):

The logical AND operator, &&,  works similarly.  If the first object is falsy, it returns that object. If it is truthy, it returns the second object. (from https://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/07/advanced-javascript-operators-and-truthy-falsy/).

Interesting stuff!

EDIT:
So, in your case, if `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, " ")` does not return a meaningful ("truthy") value, that value is returned. Otherwise, it returns `s.getPropertyValue(name)`.

Comment: ok great. wasn't sure if it tried to return two values. makes perfect sense

Comment: upvoted you just for your user name. Dinsdaaaaaaale. (actually your answer looks good too)

Comment: @steve to return two values, it's common to use an object or array since deconstruction got so easy nowadays. example: `function doStuff () { return [a, b] }; const [a, b] = doStuff()`

Answer (score 16):

The AND && operator does the following:

- Evaluate operands from left to right.
- For each operand, convert it to a boolean. If the **result** is false, stop and return the original value of that **result**.
- If all other operands have been assessed (i.e. all were truthy), return the last operand.

As I said, each operand is convert to a boolean, if it's 0 it's **falsy** and every other value different than 0 (1, 56, -2, etc etc) are **truthy**

In other words, AND returns the first falsy value or the last value if none were found.

```
// if the first operand is truthy,
// AND returns the second operand:
return 1 && 0 // 0
return 1 && 5 // 5

// if the first operand is falsy,
// AND returns it. The second operand is ignored
return null && 5 // null
return 0 && "no matter what"  // 0
```

We can also pass several values in a row. See how the first falsy one is returned:

```
return 1 && 2 && null && 3 // null
```

When all values are truthy, the last value is returned:

```
return 1 && 2 && 3 // 3, the last one
```

You can learn more about the logical operator here https://javascript.info/logical-operators