# Confusion on inferred return type

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions, return-type

I was working with Typescript and got confused with how the compiler infers the return types differently for these two functions.

```
//this is of type () => boolean | ""
const isFormValid = () => {
  return jobTitle && jobTitle!=''
}

//this is of type () => boolean
const isFormInvalid = () => {
  return !jobTitle || jobTitle===''
}
```

Yes, `jobTitle` is a string, but shouldn't both of these be of return type `() => boolean`?

Comment: It knows `jobTitle` is a string. Clearly the predicate in the first function is different than the second; in the first, the only way the left-hand side of `&&` can be false is if `jobTitle` is the empty string. In the second, both sides of the `&&` have boolean values, so that's all the function can return.

Comment: If `jobTitle` is an empty string, `isFormValid` will return that empty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning values with &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490274/returning-with)

Comment: Tangential: I'd write one in terms of the other to reduce duplication and potential errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isFormValid('') === '' // true
```

If you want boolean as returned value use double `!`:

```
const isFormValid = () => {
  return !!jobTitle && jobTitle!=''
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a && b` returns `a` if it's "falsy". `0`, `null`, `undefined` and the empty string are all "falsy".

Answer (score 2):

It is expected behavior. For explanation, let's start with `||` operator.
`||` takes the value on the right side if the value on the left is falsy.

```
const value = false || 0 // 0
const value2 = true || 0 // true
```

The `""` is also considered a falsy value:

```
const value3 = "" || "str" // "str"
```

With the `&&`, it assigns the left value if it is falsy, otherwise the right one:

```
const value1 = false && "str" // false;
const value2 = true && "str"  // str;
```

Since `jobTitle` is a `string` it can be `""` as well and compiler infers the two possible return values:

1. When `jobTitle` is `""`: `""`
2. When `jobTitle` is not `""`: `jobTitle === ''` `boolean`